# If I have an SSD and a hard disk in a system, can the SSD act as cache for the hard disk?

Tags: partition, hard-disk, cache, ssd

Say I have some partitions; one on a SATA drive and one on an SSD. I want to create a "virtual" hybrid disk. Is this possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[bcache](http://bcache.evilpiepirate.org/) might be what you are looking for. It can act as write through or write back cache.

[ZFS](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris11/technologies/data-management-2237949.html) and [Btrfs](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) also have features to put more often used blocks on flash storage.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a set of files for which you need low latency, you can establish a RAID-1 volume that mirrors the SSD content on a hard disk. Declare the hard disk component as “write-mostly”, so that the SSD will be favored when reading. For example, if `sda` is your SSD and `sdb` is your hard disk, create a partition `sda1` that covers the whole drive, create a partition `sdb1` of the same size, and create a RAID volume with

```
mdadm --create -l 1 -n 2 /dev/md0 /dev/sda1 --write-mostly /dev/sdb1
```

Comment: This is seriously a good catch. It's a straight answer to this on AU: [Can I cache an mdadm raid with an ssd?](http://askubuntu.com/q/250205/88802) (in which I now mentioned your answer in [mine](http://askubuntu.com/a/250211/88802))

Comment: Note this means the array obviously needs to include the SSD, so using a 120GB SSD with a 2TB HDD is going to get you a 120GB array -- not what people are usually after when they want SSD caching.

Answer (score 4):

There is [flashcache](https://github.com/facebook/flashcache/). It is used by Facebook to accelerate DB-storage systems.

I haven't tried it yet, so your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 2):

Since Linux 3.9 [dm-cache](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/plain/Documentation/device-mapper/cache.txt) has been merged into the mainline tree. As per the documentation, it's specifically designed for this purpose.

> It aims to improve performance of a block device (eg, a spindle) by
>   dynamically migrating some of its data to a faster, smaller device
>   (eg, an SSD).

It will also provide write caching to some extend:

> If writeback, the default, is selected then a write to a block that is
>   cached will go only to the cache and the block will be marked dirty in
>   the metadata.

About the virtual hybrid disk you'd like to see:

> This device-mapper solution allows us to insert this caching at
>   different levels of the dm stack, for instance above the data device
>   for a thin-provisioning pool.

In other words, the dm-stack lets you use any block device/partition to become a single cached virtual disk as a storage device, just like a `/dev/md0` in a software raid set.

Answer (score 2):

[LVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_(Linux)) also allows this:

*Hybrid volumes can be created using the dm-cache target, which allows one or more fast storage devices, such as flash-based SSDs, to act as a cache for one or more slower hard disk drives.*